# Use React and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs

I'm using Express framework on NodeJS (hosted by Heroku) to create my web site. I'm also using the React framework to create my components.

I have several HTML files with `div`s inside and React components which can be rendered in those `div`s.

When a user chooses a route (e.g. `/movies`) I want to be able to associate one HTML file with a component and return it back to the user. I already looked for a solution, but all of them talk about server-side rendering and sending back HTML files.

Is there another solution?

Comment: Would you be able to give more details why you need more html files? Usually if you don't want to do server-side routing one HTML file serving as a container is enough, all the other views can be rendered straight from the Javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [react router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router#whats-it-look-like) you don't have to use server side rendering, you just need to give a react component that you want to return when a route is requested.

Comment: Would appreciate a link to good reference material. This link goes to a git project that has no documentation on how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do this now is to build a Single-Page applications and redirect all requests to `/`, and the front end routing will handle the required page to load.