# How to add React to Express.js

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router

I have got the basic files of express with express generator.
Now I want to add react to my express folder and integrate react with express. How can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use React and Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668030/use-react-and-express)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your express file, you would need to link your react folder as static assets.

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

const app = express()

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build'))); // this is where your built react js files are

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
}); // this makes sure that all paths access your react.js files
```

while in development, you can access your express app by adding a proxy option in your package.json

for example, when you start your express with

```
node index.js
```

It will be served at a localhost:3000 or something else when you specify another port like localhost:5000

In order to access the json or the data your express app is sending, you need to setup a proxy in your *client's* package.json. The proxy is used for data to be accessed, so before your client side connects to a localhost, it goes through that proxy to have access to data being sent

If for example, your express app is run at localhost:5000, add the following to your client sides package.json

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

so start your express app first then your react app, and you will have combined your react app with your express server.